# How to bind a complex dictionary to a Gridview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, data-dictionary

I've used an early binding of a **`dictionary<string, string>`** to a gridview to show Urls Text and its HRef as key-value and it works like a charm. 
But since I want to replace the dictionary with this one :

```
dictionary<string, LinkInfo>
```

the binding goes wrong! Should I handle some events like as onItemDataBound or something?
and the **LinkInfo** structure is:

```
public struct LinkInfo{
    public string href;
    public bool Enabled;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to subsribe to the OnItemDataBound event. Use a template field, insert a literal with an ID like "href"

In the OnItemDataBound event use

```
Literal _href = e.Row.FindControl("href") as Literal;  
if(_href != null)
{
  _href = ((LinkInfo)e.Row.DataItem).href;
}
```

**Edit**: I've written an article that elaborates this topic further: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/7/asp.net/gridview-overview-of-different-ways-to-bind-data-to-columns

Comment: I don't want to use template field, but you show me the way with this code. Thanks