# ASP.NET: How to display a different value returned from a database in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

**Markup:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="Server">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="status_column" HeaderText="Status" />
      <asp:BoundField ...
      <asp:BoundField ...
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code:**

```
GridView1.DataSource = _dataSet
DataBind()
```

The values stored in my database are integers, 1 - 9. Each value has an associated string value that I want displayed in my GridView. Ex: 1 = "Active"; 2 = "On Hold"; etc. How would I filter the incoming data so I can display the associated String value instead of the Integers from my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Modify your DataSet, so that it will
   containt a column for the string
   representation of the data you
   want to show.
2. Use a TemplateField
   containing a Label. Subscribe to the
   OnRowDataBound Event of the
   GridView, and get that Label with
   e.Row.FindControl("LabelID"), cast
   the e.Row.DataItem to your DataRow,
   and assign the string representation
   of your integer value there.

I would advise against the solution posted by anishmarokey, because the query is not the correct place for this. Think a little big bigger, about localization for instance. Wouldn't work with that solution, but with both of my suggested solutions.

**Edit1**:
Similiar answeres from me regarding the OnRowDataBound Event. If these don't help you, I'm afraid you need to use google to find more examples:
[Programmatically access GridView columns and manipulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272015/programmatically-access-gridview-columns-and-manipulate/2272058#2272058)
[Custom GridView delete button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458351/custom-gridview-delete-button/2458978#2458978)
[How to bind a complex dictionary to a Gridview in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985554/how-to-bind-a-complex-dictionary-to-a-gridview-in-asp-net/2985993#2985993)

**Edit2**:
I've written an article that elaborates this topic further: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/7/asp.net/gridview-overview-of-different-ways-to-bind-data-to-columns

Comment: could you possibly show an example of your two solutions? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing it in C# , If you are using SQL you can try with

when then condition in a query

```
SELECT title, price,
        Category = CASE column1
         WHEN column1 = '1' THEN 'Active'
          WHEN column1 = '2' THEN 'On Hold'
          .....
          ELSE 'your value'
        END,
FROM table
```

which then bind to the gridview

Comment: category is an alias name. this will come in .cs page to bind

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not editing in the gridview, I would just join to the FK table in the SQL and return that as the status instead of the ID.

```
--Include this as part of your select statement for the datagrid:
SELECT CategoryText as status_column
FROM status_table st INNER JOIN category_table ct ON st.status_column = ct.status_column
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is coming back from a database, I think that is is very likely that you will find at table that defines the categories.

All you have to do is join the two

```
Select Item.Id, Item.Title, Item.Price, Category.Id, Category.Name
From Item
   Inner Join Category
       ON Item.CategoryId = Category.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save a list of KeyPairValue using Dictionary and try to get the value in the View:

```
Dictionary<int,string> stringList = //Any code to fill the dictionary, now each integer is related to a string.
```

in the page

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="<%Eval(stringList[status_column])%>" HeaderText="Status" />
```

Comment: Have you tried the code? Does that work? I don't have an IDE right here, but shouldn't it look like this: '<% this.stringList[Eval("status_column")]%>', or '<% this.stringList[Eval("status_column")];%>'

Comment: ooops, sorry it's my fault, i didn't try the code, but i wanted the idea to be clear. citronas, i think your code is correct.